Finding all $ f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} $ s.t.: $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - 3 \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0 $
I need to find all continuously differentiable functions $ f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} $    such that
$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - 3 \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0. $
I was given the hint of writing every $f$ as $f(x,y) = F(u(x,y), v(x,y))$, such that $ F: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} $ and $u(x,y) = ax+by,$ $v(x,y) = cx+dy$ for some $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$, and get to a place where there's only dependency on one variable of $F.$
Furthermore, the hint also said to look for the meaning of $(x,y) \mapsto (u(x,y), v(x,y))$ being reversible (i.e. $ab - cd \neq 0$), but I don't realy understand how this will help me to find $f.$
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
edit:
In the original post, I messed up the hint and wrote it as:
$u(x,y) = (ax,by),$ $v(x,y) = (cx,dy)$.
I re-edited it so it'll show the correct hint.

Do you understand the geometry of $\nabla f$ and level curves if $f$? This equation tells you that $\nabla f$ is parallel to $(3,1)$.

Are you sure the hint isn't $u(x,y)=ax+by, v(x,y)=cx+dy$?

It's overkill here (especially if the hint is as @Gonçalo indicated) but another route is the method of characteristics. This yields the characteristic equations as  $x'=1,y'=-3,f'=0$ which implies that $f$ is constant along the characteristic lines.

@Gonçalo yes you're right! I misread the hint given to me, sorry about that. I'll re-edit the post, thank for bringing it to my attention

As highlighted by Gonçalo in his comment, your hint aimed to consider the following change of variables :
$$
\begin{cases}
   u = ax+by \\
   v = cx+dy
\end{cases}
$$
Now, you can rewrite the differential equation for $f(x,y) = F(u,v)$ thanks to the chain rule and get :
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - 3\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} 
   = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} - 3\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} 
   = (a-3b)\frac{\partial F}{\partial u} + (c-3d)\frac{\partial F}{\partial v} 
   = 0
$$
Taking $a = 3b$ but $c \neq 3d$, this equation is simplified into $\frac{\partial F}{\partial v} = 0$, meaning that $F$ depends only on $u$, i.e. $F(u,v) = g(u)$. In the end, it implies $f(x,y) = g(a(3x+y)) = h(3x+y)$, where $h$ is another arbitrary function $-$ equivalently, we may set $a = 1$.
N.B. : the statement about $ad-bc \neq 0$ is a mere caveat in order to ensure the invertibility of the linear transformation, otherwise we wouldn't be able to get back to the initial parametrization and recover $f$.

The condition is equivalent to $\nabla f \cdot (1,-3) = 0$. We can use this fact and the gradient theorem to evaluate:
$$
f(\vec{a}+t_0(1,-3)) - f(\vec{a}) = \int_{\vec{a}}^{\vec{a}+t_0(1,-3)} \nabla f \cdot d\vec{r} = \int_{0}^{t_0}\nabla \underbrace{f(\vec{a}+t(1,-3)) \cdot (1,-3)}_{=0} dt = 0
$$
In other words $f(\vec{a}) = f(\vec{a}+t_0(1,-3))$,
which holds for all $\vec{a},t_0$.
If we now write $\vec{a} = (x,y), t_0 = y/3$, we find that:
$$
f(x,y) = f(x+\frac{y}{3},0)
$$
Therefore the general solution is $f(x,y) = g(x+y/3)$, for any sufficiently differentiable function $g(u)$.
